# Find the continuous solution to the differential equation.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The following differential equation is given

$$3(x^2+7)\frac{d}{dx}y(x)+2xy(x)=\sigma(x)x-\sigma(x-1)x,$$

in which $\sigma(x)$ is a step function. The initial condition is given by $y(1) = 0$.

I'm not sure how to solve this. I know how to solve linear differential equations and second order differential equations but I have not come across this.

Comment: cannot see the image

Comment: @SakethMalyala it has been edited.

Comment: @E--: I edited your question and changed the formulation of the right-hand side by introducing the step function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the question into two domains $D_1 = (-\infty,0]\cup [1,\infty)$ and $D_2=(0,1)$. On $D_1$ we have

$$3(x^2+7)\frac{d}{dx}y(x)+2xy(x)=0$$
$$\implies \dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{2x}{3(x^2+7)}y$$
$$\implies \dfrac{dy}{y}=\dfrac{2x}{3(x^2+7)}dx$$
$$\implies \int_{y_0}^{y}\dfrac{d\bar{y}}{\bar{y}}=\int_{x_0}^x\dfrac{2\bar{x}}{3(\bar{x}^2+7)}d\bar{x}.$$

It is important to note that the initial condition for the second part of the domain $D_1$ can only be determined after the solution for $D_2$ is obtained.

In the domain $D_2$ we have

$$3(x^2+7)\frac{d}{dx}y(x)+2xy(x)=1$$

This is a linear differential equation. We need to solve the homogeneous differential equation $3(x^2+7)\frac{d}{dx}y_\text{h}(x)+2xy_\text{h}(x)=0$ (we solved this befor) and you need to determine the particular solution $y_\text{p}$ (by variation of constants or by an ansatz. Here $y_\text{p}=\text{const.}$ will be sufficient as ansatz).

The general solution is given by

$$y(x) = y_\text{h}+y_\text{p}.$$

Note that the initial conditions need to be calculated from the solution in the time interval before this domain.

Comment: How did you get from the first step to the second step?

Comment: What do you mean by the second step?

Comment: from 3(^2+7)()/dx + 2()=0 to /=2^3(^2+7). Is this just arranging?
Also how would you use the linear equation to solve the second part of the D1?

Comment: It is the rewritten equation. When you have the general solution for the first half of $D_1$ you use the initial condition (IC) to remove the constants of integration. Then you plug in the $x$ value for which the second domain starts. This value will be the IC for the solution of $D_2$. Then you determine the constants of integration for the general solution on $D_2$. Again plug in the $x$ value for which the second half of$D_1$ starts. This point will be the IC for the second half of $D_1$. Use the general solution for the first part of $D_1$ and determine the constant of integration.

Comment: I got y = In(x^2 + 7) - In(8)^(-1/3) as the solution to the homogenous part (-∞,0). Is this correct?

Comment: @E—: You can verify the solution by plugging it into the ode for the specific domain. Additionally you have to check the initial condition.

Comment: I'm going to summarise what i understand:
(1) For D1 it is the homogenous equations and for 1=(−∞,0] I have to use the IC y(1) = 0 to get the constant. 
(2) Then I sub in x = 0 (from D2) to the first homogeneous equation (−∞,0] to get a value for y [so the IC is y(0) = 0]
(3) I sub in y(0) = 0 into non homogeneous (D2) to get the constant -- Also did you mean to write x instead of 1 for D2 equation?
(4) Then sub in x = 0 into D2 equation to get y [IC is y(0) = 'number']
(5) Use (4) IC for D1 (homogenous) second part to get a different constant. 
Is this right?

Comment: Also is the method you described general or does it only work for this particular question?

Comment: @E-- Whenever you have a differential equation with different domains you can apply this method.

Comment: @ MachineLearner: Wait 0 and 1 are not part of the domain of the function. Also what if D2 had 2 parts and D1 had 1.